# Adding a post notice should not end a review

Tags: bug, review, moderator-tools

When handling the review queues, for example first posts or low quality posts, if I add a post notice, the page advances to the next item in the queue, and without incrementing the review count for review badge progress.

- The page should not advance: I might want to vote on the post, or add a comment, before explicitly clicking **I'm Done** when I'm done. The obvious workaround is to make the post notice my last action, do everything else first. But I rarely need to add a post notice, and tend to forget this unreasonable detail.
- Adding post notice (while processing the review queue) should count for review badge progress.

The special treatment of post notices is unexpected, unusual, and inconvenient.

Comment: Solving the first issue seems like it would solve the second as well since then you'd have to either perform another action that *does* end the review (thus incrementing badge progress) or Skip/close the tab (thus not completing the review)

Comment: I thought so too. But I added that 2nd point anyway for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

> When handling the review queues, for example first posts or low quality posts, if I add a post notice, the page advances to the next item in the queue

I'm not sure when they fixed this, but it doesn't happen anymore; the page reloads and you stay in the current review item so you can vote or add a comment.

> Adding post notice (while processing the review queue) should count for review badge progress.

In the Low Quality Posts, you still have to make a review decision (Looks OK / Edit / Delete). I noticed that in the First Posts and Late Answers, adding a post notice still **doesn't count** as an action, so the I'm Done button is not activated.